# converting RegExp to String then back to RegExp

Tags: javascript, regex

So I have a RegExp `regex = /asd/`

I am storing it as a as a key in my key-val store system.

So I say `str = String(regex)` which returns `"/asd/"`.

Now I need to convert that string back to a RegExp.

So I try: `RegExp(str)` and I see `/\/asd\//`

this is not what I want. It is not the same as `/asd/`

Should I just remove the first and last characters from the string before converting it to regex? That would get me the desired result in this situation, but wouldn't necessarily work if the RegExp had modifiers like `/i` or `/g`

Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: Does `(new RegExp(regex)).source()` help before storage? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/source

Comment: @jedifans I see what you're saying, yeah that should work. That way I'm not storing the slashes in the string

Comment: I shall convert it to an answer :)

Comment: You see `/\/asd\//` ? How do you see that ? Using `new RegExp(str)` the 'str' variable contains a string that needs no delimiter. The delimiter is a language level parse, once it's in a variable, it's already been parsed.

Comment: @sln `RegExp(String(/asd/))` returns `/\/asd\//`

Comment: Looks like `String()`, whatever that is, is taking a _regex_ object and turning it into another regex object. wth?

Comment: @sln  I'm saving the string to a key-val store, then need to read it and evaluate it as a regex

Comment: Just a side note, you should store the parameters (regex options) that are to be used with that regex into a hash (using same key)  as well. So, if you can't get structures in JS, make two hash stores, one for the regex _raw_ string (no delimiters), one for it's options. Otherwise, it's just junk.

Comment: @sln do you think the answer by 4castle is junk? Seems like you can use a regex to parse the string `"/asd/i"` into the regex `/asd/i`

Comment: In ES6 there is also [flags](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/flags) along with `source`, but it's not widely supported yet.

Comment: Well, to be fair, I didn't read any of the answers. From like 15 years of Perl, I've gleaned that pre-compiled regexes of the form `/../xxx`, can't contain all the modifiers available at the time of execution. If it can't do that, it's better to have it all available in a hash, or if it applies to all of them (like 'g') then it doesn't matter. Usually, you'd take the path of least resistance, but if you don't know if it works for every thing, it's better to be conservative and slightly basic. The foundation of good code.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

```
const regex = /asd/gi;
```

### converting RegExp to String

```
const obj = {flags: regex.flags, source: regex.source};
const string = JSON.stringify(obj);
```

### then back to RegExp

```
const obj2 = JSON.parse(string);
const regex2 = new RegExp(obj2.source, obj2.flags);
```

Requires ES6+.

Answer (score 71):

If you don't need to store the modifiers, you can use [`Regexp#source`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/source) to get the string value, and then convert back using the `RegExp` constructor.

```
var regex = /abc/g;
var str = regex.source; // "abc"
var restoreRegex = new RegExp(str, "g");
```

---

If you do need to store the modifiers, use a regex to parse the regex:

```
var regex = /abc/g;
var str = regex.toString(); // "/abc/g"
var parts = /\/(.*)\/(.*)/.exec(str);
var restoredRegex = new RegExp(parts[1], parts[2]);
```

This will work even if the pattern has a `/` in it, because `.*` is greedy, and will advance to the last `/` in the string.

If performance is a concern, use normal string manipulation using [`String#lastIndexOf`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/lastIndexOf):

```
var regex = /abc/g;
var str = regex.toString(); // "/abc/g"
var lastSlash = str.lastIndexOf("/");
var restoredRegex = new RegExp(str.slice(1, lastSlash), str.slice(lastSlash + 1));
```

Comment: I suppose it's also worth mentioning you could just do `var restoredRegex = eval(str);` but that will be slower, and has the ability to execute arbitrary JavaScript.

Comment: How about `regex.toString().split('/')`

Comment: @Xotic750 That will fail if a `/` is in the regex pattern itself

Comment: @4castle genious solution ! :D

Comment: So close to greatness -- 

`var restoredRegex = RegExp.apply(RegExp, str.match(/\/(.*)\/(.*)/));`

Comment: A different problem: Using `new RegExp('\n', 'g')` gives me a different string result than `/\n/g`. Looks like the backslash has to be escaped in the string. Also, I think one can also use `var regex = /abc\n/g;
var str = regex.source;
var flags = regex.flags;
var restoredRegex = new RegExp(str, flags);` -- I think this is cleaner than the string parsing. Of course, it is _two_ strings instead of just one.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the following before storage of your regex literal:

```
(new RegExp(regex)).source
```

See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/source

Example:

```
regex = /asd/

string = (new RegExp(regex)).source
// string is now "asd"

regex = RegExp(string)
// regex has the original value /asd/
```

Comment: And if it is `regex = /asd/ig`? Also, it should be `source`, not `source()`.

Comment: Why are you calling `new RegExp`? It's already a regex. Wouldn't you just do `string = regex.source`?

Comment: True @WiktorStribiżew, source does not take account of that, though I suppose `.flags` could be stored too.

@4castle, I wasn't sure if a regex literal was actually a RegExp instance.

Comment: Ah, well yes. A regex literal is syntactic sugar for making a RegExp instance.

Answer (score 1):

`let rx = RegExp.apply(RegExp, str.match(/\/(.*)\/(.*)/).slice(1));`

A modified version of [@PegasusEpsilon](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2105716/pegasus-epsilon) answer

Comment: ES6+ syntax should be `RegExp(...str.match(/\/(.*)\/(.*)/).slice(1))`

Answer (score 1):

StackOverflow saves the day again, thanks @4castle! I wanted to store some regex rules in a JS file, and some in a DB, combine them into an array of objects like so:

```
module.exports = {
    [SETTINGS.PRODUCTION_ENV]: [

        {
            "key": /<meta name="generator"[\s\S]*?>/gmi,
            "value": "",
            "regex": true
        },

        ...
    ]
}
```

Then, loop through each environment's objects and apply it to a string of text. This is for a node/lambda project, so I wanted to use ES6. I used @4castle's code, with some destructuring, and I ended up with this:

```
    let content = body;
    const regexString = replacement.key.toString();
    const regexParts = /\/(.*)\/(.*)/.exec(regexString);
    const {1: source, 2: flags} = regexParts;
    const regex = new RegExp(source, flags);
    content = content.replace(regex, replacement.value);
    
    return content;
```

Works a treat!

Answer (score 0):

Another option based on previous answers:

```
const strToRegex = str => new RegExp(str.slice(1,str.lastIndexOf('/')), str.slice(str.lastIndexOf('/')+1));
let initRegex = /asd/i;
let newRegex = strToRegex(initRegex.toString());
```