# Assert RegExp with Mocha and Chai

Tags: javascript, mocha.js, chai, assertions

I need to assert a function that should return constant RegExp where pattern and modifiers are fixed. How one could do that with Mocha?

Given the test code like this:

```
var expect = require("chai").expect;

describe("myRegExp() function", function () {
    it("returns constant pattern", function () {

        expect(myRegExp()).to.equal(/somePattern/i);

    });
});

var myRegExp = function(){
    return /somePattern/i;
}
```

We get an AssertionError:

```
AssertionError: expected /somePattern/i to equal /somePattern/i
    at Context.<anonymous> (test/stackSnippetTest.js:6:31)
```

Comment: try to use https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/escape when you compare

Answer (score 1):

```js
it("Compare Complex Objects", () => {
  let regex1 = /somePattern/i;
  let regex2 = /somePattern/i;
  assert.deepEqual(regex1, regex2);
  expect(regex1).to.deep.equal(regex2);
});
```

Deep Equals is loose equality, while assert.equal is strict equality.  Similar to comparing two dates, or the string `"42"` and the number `42`.  If it's an object and it's not the exact same object, you must use the 'deep' qualifier.

Answer (score 0):

RegExp can be converted to String. See [Edwin](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1595977/edwin) comments, [RegExp docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp) and also here [converting RegExp to String then back to RegExp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39154255/converting-regexp-to-string-then-back-to-regexp)

The solution is to use RegExp.toString():

```
var expect = require("chai").expect;

describe("myRegExp() function", function () {
    it("returns constant pattern", function () {

        expect(myRegExp().toString()).to.equal(/somePattern/i.toString());

    });
});

var myRegExp = function(){
    return /somePattern/i;
}
```

which works just fine. Alternatively, assert both RegExp.source and RegExp.flags:

```
    expect(myRegExp().source).to.equal(/somePattern/i.source);
    expect(myRegExp().flags).to.equal(/somePattern/i.flags);
```