# How to convert regex string to regex expression?

Tags: javascript, regex

How can I convert regex String (which includes start and end parameters) to RexExp object?

RexExp doesn't accept start and end parameters I think.

```
new RegExp("/^........$/")  // not working
new RegExp("........");  //working
```

Here is some example regex strings I need to validate with;

```
var regex = "/^........$/";
var regex2 = "/^........$/i";
```

Comment: forward slashes `/` are regex delimiter they must not be inside double quotes, just remove double quotes in first expression

Comment: Strip the `/`s (use `slice` or `substr`, already answered somewhere) and pass to `RegExp` constructor like what you're using. Or alternatively `eval` (<-- don't ever do this).

Comment: Also... why do you need those regex strings in the first place?

Comment: Have you read the [documentation of `RegExp`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions)?

Comment: you can do either `new RegExp(/...../)` or `new RegExp(".....")` (no slashes). Slashes are reserved for RegExp literal expressions

Comment: @NahuelFouilleul How can I remove double quotes? Its a string variable.

Comment: maybe commented to quickly, you have to remove `/` and use the flags as second argument

Comment: See [converting RegExp to String then back to RegExp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39154255/converting-regexp-to-string-then-back-to-regexp).

Comment: @NahuelFouilleul Is there a way to remove start and end slashes? Because regex content also can have slashes like /^[a-zA-Z0-9.!#$%&'*+/=?^...$/ and it can have flags like regex2. So I also need to get these flags.